# Context for MGT SharePointProvider

Tags: javascript, authentication, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph Toolkit components in SharePoint but outside of the SharePoint Framework.

I found how to load the components, and a sample to initiate the authentication:

`mgt.Providers.globalProvider = new mgt.SharePointProvider(this.context);`

My question: what part of `this.context` does `SharePointProvider` actually need to initiate the authentication? I don't have a `this.context` in my case and I am trying to build the argument from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The needed part is the `aadTokenProviderFactory` available here : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/blob/main/packages/providers/mgt-sharepoint-provider/src/SharePointProvider.ts#L97-L102

This is how we authenticate using the built-in and provided AAD app from SPFx. This should be available within any web part.